# Browser Redirects http://localhost to https://localhost When Forwarded Port Included in URL

Tags: localhost, portforwarding

I have Apache listening on port 80 on Ubuntu Desktop. The URLs `http://localhost`, `http://localhost:80`, `http://127.0.0.1` and `http://127.0.0.1:80` all display Apache's default page as expected. When I use `http://localhost:8888` or `http://127.0.0.1:8888` the browser is understandably unable to reach that page. The URL's not re-written nor is there any redirect.

However, if I forward port `8888` using `ssh user@203.0.113.5 -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -N &` the URL `http://localhost:8888` results in a **301 Moved Permanently** redirect to `https://localhost` which is also unreachable.

The browser has Automatic HTTPS disabled, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` have been deleted from the its HSTS policy, the cache has been disabled in its developer tools and I've even used a private browsing session, but still the 301 redirect.

This happens with Edge on Ubuntu Desktop and macOS, Safari and Firefox on macOS, Apache installed locally on Ubuntu and macOS and through MAMP or XAMPP on macOS which leads me to think there's an issue with the port forwarding command or the remote server, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Regards, Steve.